# Securely create a connection between Android app and Amazon S3 using Cognito Identity Pool Id

Tags: android, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

We have created a mobile app for Android and integrated Amazon S3 bucket using AWS Mobile SDK for Android. We have followed the below links to integrate AWS S3 in our android app.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/setup.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/s3transferutility.html

We are using Amazon S3 in client app to store & retrieve user files. So we are using Cognito Identity Pool Id & CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider to create a connection between Amazon S3 & client app. We are using separate web service call (using SSL for security) to get Cognito Pool Id from server & use it in SDK instead of hardcoding it inside app source.

If someone found the Cognito Identity Pool Id and API URL details, they can get the access to our resources. We are using SSL layer to make the API calls secured. But still, we should pass Cognito Identity Pool Id to Amazon S3 in a secure way. Please anyone provide us a solution/way to resolve this problem as soon as possible as it is a very critical problem for us?

Comment: Are you using identity pools with federation or external identity providers? What's your identity provider? Are you using authenticated roles or unauthenticated roles?

Comment: We are using unauthenticated roles & not using any identity providers and assigned full access to unauthenticated user role while creating Cognito pool id and using that pool id in my app to connect Amazon S3 bucket.

Comment: My understanding is that unauthenticated roles facilitate scenarios like guest access, or you can use them for read-only operations. You should probably look into using an authenticated role to do those operations. On a side note, no matter how you try to hide the way you pass the pool ID to the client application, security best practices dictates that you can't trust the client. Anyone can de-compile your app and figure out your pool ID. All you'll be doing is security by obscurity. That information should be treated as public.

Comment: @RajkumarG have you find a way to secure you bucket information??